# Using jquery detach() twice doesn't work as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-autocomplete, detach

I have a autocomplete textbox in my DOM (using jquery). I have scenario where in I need to show this autocomplete textbox in dialog box on click of a button. Do autocomplete stuff in dialog view only and then set the autocomplete textbox back to DOM when I close the dialog. Here's the sample:

```
$("#autocom-div button").click(function(){
    $("#autocom-div #autocomplete").detach().dialog({
        close: function(){
            $(this).removeClass('ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content').removeAttr('style');
            $('#autocom-div button').before(this);
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle link for the same:

http://jsfiddle.net/s24101984/EBduF/350/

Problem: When I click the button second time

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with `detach()`, it's rather with `dialog()`. You have to destroy the existed instance of the dialog before creating another one. Because the destroy method would also remove the `div` was hosting you need to clone it first like this:

```
$("#autocom-div button").click(function()
{
    var parent = $("#autocom-div"),
        elm    = $("#autocomplete"),
        clone  = $("#autocomplete").clone();

    $("#autocomplete").detach().dialog({
         close: function(){
             parent.prepend(clone);
             $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
         }
    });

});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/uWPUr/)

Comment: the autocomplete plug-in is not working when I open it second time. Please let me know if I missed something.

Comment: like `dialog()` you need to destroy and reassign `autocomplete()`, see the updated demo.